# I am having trouble updating node and npm

Tags: node.js, npm, ubuntu-18.04

I'm currently using Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS and I want to upgrade nodejs to version 16 but, unable to.
I have almost spent 4 hours trying to resolve this and stackoverflow is my last option.

**Problems**

1. Sudo apt-get update gives:
   [error about some docker repo 404  Not Found [IP: 13.35.169.116 443]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwMO2.png)
2. I followed this [tutorial](https://tecadmin.net/upgrade-nodejs-via-npm/) and it did not help.
3. Running `node --version` gives **v0.10.31**
4. Running `npm --version` gives [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1o1V.png)

Comment: For managing Node installations (even just for installing Node), I strongly suggest using https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node is not up to date in ubuntu's ppa. I would recommend just using nvm ( node version manager ) to install the version you need: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/blob/master/README.md